# How do I perform a stochastic integration by parts?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

There is a statement in my book that states:

> Stochastic integration by parts implies that
>
> $$  \int_t^T x(u)du = Tx(T) - tx(t) - \int_t^T u dx(u) = \int_t^T (T-u)  dx(u) + (T-t)x(t) $$

Can someone please explain to me how this happens? I'd really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the integration by parts formula follows by applying Itô's lemma to the function $g(x,y) = xy$; from that you get: $$d(XY)_t = X_t dY_t + Y_t dX_t + dX_t dY_t$$

If you now set $dY_t = du$, you get the formula you wrote down.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Does that mean in this case $g(x,y) = xu $?

Comment: @coffee-raid No. The variables I'm using are $x$ and $y$ so $g$ is the product of $x$ and $y$.